# Entity Framework 4.3 DbContext SaveChanges updates more records than expected

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, savechanges

I'm using Entity Framework 4.3 and DbContext to update my db. I have a collection of Users that permits any user to be modified and then changes saved. My problem is that I'm finding an extra record is being updated unexpectedly when calling SaveChanges().

For example, updating user with pk = 5 to 'revoked' status also generates a sql update for user with pk = 1

SQL profiler trace:

(NOT EXPECTING THIS)

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @p int
update [db].[Users]
set @p = 0
where (([UsersPk] = @0) and ([RowVersion] = @1))
select [RowVersion]
from [db].[Users]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [UsersPk] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=0x0000000000011BFD
```

(EXPECTED)

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [db].[Users]
set [AccessStatus] = @0
where (([UsersPk] = @1) and ([RowVersion] = @2))
select [RowVersion]
from [db].[Users]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [UsersPk] = @1',N'@0 varchar(10),@1 int,@2 binary(8)',@0='revoked',@1=5,@2=0x0000000000011C01
```

To debug this I used this

```
var mods = DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<User>().Where(u => u.State == EntityState.Modified);
Debug.Print(mods.Count().ToString());
```

to get the number of modified entries which returns 1, but the call to SaveChanges() returns 2, as indeed it should as 2 entries are updated.

I can't figure out why the first query is generated as the properties for this user are not being updated - well they shouldn't be anyway.

I suspect I'm overlooking something fairly straightforward here but can't figure out what. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: We can't read your mind as to what you are doing with the context

Comment: I'm modifying an entity and calling SaveChanges() as described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in .NET 4 that is fixed in the upcoming .NET 4.5 release and for which a fix is also available as a hotfix. The bug shows up on EF 4.3 since it is based on the underlying .NET 4 core libraries.

The details of the hotfix are here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624

You will need to contact Microsoft Customer Service and Support to obtain the hotfix. However, like I said, the bug is also fixed in .NET 4.5, which will be in beta any day now.

Unfortunately there aren't any good general workarounds.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer and will wait for the .Net 4.5 Beta to see if this resolves. Thanks for the input ajcvickers.

Comment: .NET 4.5 and EF 5.0 beta1 are out today. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/29/ef4-3-1-and-ef5-beta-1-available-on-nuget.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I'm using Windows XP so can't use it.